# Page Reload WithOut Refresh in Ruby On Rails on DatePicker Select Event?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, page-refresh, partial-page-refresh

My Scenario as Follows

When i change date the corresponding appointment list will change.

My Controller as Follows

```
def  index
 if (params[:appdate]!=nil)

  @t=params[:appdate]


 else

  @t=Date.today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")


 end
end
```

and View as Follows

```
<h1>PatientDashBoard</h1>


    Date is<%=@t%>
    <%= form_tag('/patientdashboard') do %>
 <table>
<tr>

<td><div id="appointmentdate"></div></td>
<%=hidden_field_tag 'appdate'%>
</tr>

</table>

<% end %>
```

and My application.js as follows

```
$(function() {
$("#appointmentdate").datepicker({
    onSelect : function(dateText, inst) {
         $("#appdate").val(dateText);
         var date=$("#appdate").val();
        // alert(date);
         $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
    }
})
 });
```

Then How to Write index.js.erb file without refreshing whole page just update the @t value can u please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax. I didn't tested it. Let me know if any issue..

```
$(function() {
$("#appointmentdate").datepicker({
    onSelect : function(dateText, inst) {
         $("#appdate").val(dateText);
         var date=$("#appdate").val();
            $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "script",
              url: window.location.href,
              data: { appdate: date},
             });
             return false;
    }
})
});
```

Comment: add code into the index.js.erb to make ny change in the view. For testing add alert("Got it");. This will help (http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery)

Comment: Check the rails log after changing the date whether the request is getting or not. Also check your index is responding to js or not.

Comment: date is changed and js also respnding but the value of c doesn't change

Comment: <div id="selected_date">Date is<%=@t%></div>;(make this change in index.html.erb). $("#selected_date").html("Date is"+<%= params[:appdate] %>);(in index.js.erb)